# how to update column value depends on another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to update column values depends on another column values at same table in sql-server

```
id  loc_id  joc_id
246 601 
247 602 
249 604 
251 606 
253 608 
254 609 
330 41  601
338 68  601
332 50  602
358 52  602
335 63  604
341 71  606
342 72  606
349 48  606
347 46  608
348 47  609
```

I want to make update query which must set `id` in `joc_id` where `joc_id = loc_id`.
Output should be like:

```
    id loc_id joc_id
    246 601 
    247 602 
    249 604 
    251 606 
    253 608 
    254 609 
    330 41  246
    338 68  246
    332 50  247
    358 52  247
    335 63  249
    341 71  251
    342 72  251
    349 48  251
    347 46  253
    348 47  254
```

Comment: What is your question here exactly? I don't understand your vague description of what your trying to do here.. What have you tried to solve the problem yourself? What are you expected results?

Comment: I want to update table set joc_id=id where joc_id=loc_id
in joc_id instead of 601 it should 246 .. and all must like this in one query

Comment: Repeating yourself doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making `self-join`(if I understand the question correctly). I assumed that the first 6 rows have `NULLs` in `joc_id`.

```
update y1
set y1.joc_id = y2.id
from yourTable as y1
join yourTable as y2
    on y1.joc_id = y2.loc_id
where y1.joc_id is not null
```

Comment: if the answer is correct please mark it as an answer. thanks